# Expectations unmatched : Golang unit test error

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, go-testing

I am new to Golang,I am getting below error when I try to run below testcase. Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

```
db, mock, _ := sqlmock.New()

    dbConnect, _ := services.DB.Connect(services.Config.Database)
    defer db.Close()

    rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "txid", "nounce", "amount", "confirmations", "fromAddress", "toAddress", "toAccountId", "currencyId",
        "processStateId", "transactionTypeId", "transactionFees", "gasPrice", "gasLimit", "transactionIndex", "logIndex", "gasUsed",
        "status", "blockNumber", "createdAt", "updatedAt"}).
        AddRow("039f79c1-dbb3-4439-b9f7-361c7db6e03f", "0x642ec5ca327d0e64e958b1f9a6ef1feb61f0e541629b3769e854608d00d89744", 0, 0.01, 12, "0x3ee9f8c6a2676f2b0ebc324747253a23b7dbd1b3",
            "0x06fcd7f32e155be895ed9282446864e7397ae40d", "77c93121-5a9a-48fa-8c2f-23ff1debc3df", 2, 3, 2, 0.001, 0.001, 210000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00", "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00").
        AddRow("039f79c1-dbb3-4439-b9f7-361c7db6e03f", "0x642ec5ca327d0e64e958b1f9a6ef1feb61f0e541629b3769e854608d00d89744", 0, 0.01, 12, "0x3ee9f8c6a2676f2b0ebc324747253a23b7dbd1b3",
            "0x06fcd7f32e155be895ed9282446864e7397ae40d", "77c93121-5a9a-48fa-8c2f-23ff1debc3df", 2, 3, 2, 0.001, 0.001, 210000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00", "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00")

    GetTransactionsQuery(dbConnect, "25", "0")
    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT * FROM BlockchainTransactions limit $1 offset $2").WithArgs("25", "0").WillReturnRows(rows)

    if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("there were unfulfilled expectations: %s", err)
    }
```

```
--- FAIL: Test_GetTransactionsQuery (7.79s)
    ethtransactions_test.go:51: there were unfulfilled expectations: there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which:
          - matches sql: 'SELECT * FROM BlockchainTransactions limit $1 offset $2'
          - is with arguments:
            0 - 25
            1 - 0
          - should return rows:
            row 0 - [039f79c1-dbb3-4439-b9f7-361c7db6e03f 0x642ec5ca327d0e64e958b1f9a6ef1feb61f0e541629b3769e854608d00d89744 0 0.01 12 0x3ee9f8c6a2676f2b0ebc324747253a23b7dbd1b3 0x06fcd7f32e155be895ed9282446864e7397ae40d 77c93121-5a9a-48fa-8c2f-23ff1debc3df 2 3 2 0.001 0.001 210000 0 0 0 0 0 2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00 2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00]
            row 1 - [039f79c1-dbb3-4439-b9f7-361c7db6e03f 0x642ec5ca327d0e64e958b1f9a6ef1feb61f0e541629b3769e854608d00d89744 0 0.01 12 0x3ee9f8c6a2676f2b0ebc324747253a23b7dbd1b3 0x06fcd7f32e155be895ed9282446864e7397ae40d 77c93121-5a9a-48fa-8c2f-23ff1debc3df 2 3 2 0.001 0.001 210000 0 0 0 0 0 2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00 2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00]
FAIL
```

Below is the Function I am trying to mock:

```
func GetTransactionsQuery(db *sqlx.DB, limit string, offset string) ([]Transactions, error) {

    transactions := []Transactions{}
    Query := `SELECT *
    FROM "BlockchainTransactions"
    LIMIT :limit
    OFFSET :offset`
    params := map[string]interface{}{
        "limit":  limit,
        "offset": offset,
    }

    rows, err := db.NamedQuery(Query, params)

    for rows.Next() {
        transaction := Transactions{}
        rows.StructScan(&transaction)
        transactions = append(transactions, transaction)
    }
    rows.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(`GetTransactionsQuery: Failed to execute query`, err)
        return transactions, err
    }

    return transactions, nil
}
```

Edit:
I am calling an actual function before I mock data; I am still getting same error.

Comment: After you set the expectations, you should run the function under test before checking if the expectations were met. Based on your code, you are not calling the function under test

Comment: Thanks @BurakSerdar. I have updated my code. I am still getting same error. Can you please suggest if I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What @Burak Serdar means is that your expectations must be declared before you actually call your function that triggers mock. It means your test code should be

```
db, mock, _ := sqlmock.New()

dbConnect, _ := services.DB.Connect(services.Config.Database)
defer db.Close()

rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "txid", "nounce", "amount", "confirmations", "fromAddress", "toAddress", "toAccountId", "currencyId",
    "processStateId", "transactionTypeId", "transactionFees", "gasPrice", "gasLimit", "transactionIndex", "logIndex", "gasUsed",
    "status", "blockNumber", "createdAt", "updatedAt"}).
    AddRow("039f79c1-dbb3-4439-b9f7-361c7db6e03f", "0x642ec5ca327d0e64e958b1f9a6ef1feb61f0e541629b3769e854608d00d89744", 0, 0.01, 12, "0x3ee9f8c6a2676f2b0ebc324747253a23b7dbd1b3",
        "0x06fcd7f32e155be895ed9282446864e7397ae40d", "77c93121-5a9a-48fa-8c2f-23ff1debc3df", 2, 3, 2, 0.001, 0.001, 210000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00", "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00").
    AddRow("039f79c1-dbb3-4439-b9f7-361c7db6e03f", "0x642ec5ca327d0e64e958b1f9a6ef1feb61f0e541629b3769e854608d00d89744", 0, 0.01, 12, "0x3ee9f8c6a2676f2b0ebc324747253a23b7dbd1b3",
        "0x06fcd7f32e155be895ed9282446864e7397ae40d", "77c93121-5a9a-48fa-8c2f-23ff1debc3df", 2, 3, 2, 0.001, 0.001, 210000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00", "2021-10-30 07:38:03.299+00")

//expect first
mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT * FROM BlockchainTransactions limit $1 offset $2").WithArgs("25", "0").WillReturnRows(rows)
// trigger your code
    GetTransactionsQuery(dbConnect, "25", "0")

if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
    t.Errorf("there were unfulfilled expectations: %s", err)
 }
```

It's better to go thrugh and understand how to use [go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock).

[Suggestion] Also in your code check your error first

```golang
func GetTransactionsQuery(db *sqlx.DB, limit string, offset string) ([]Transactions, error) {

    transactions := []Transactions{}
    Query := `SELECT *
    FROM "BlockchainTransactions"
    LIMIT :limit
    OFFSET :offset`
    params := map[string]interface{}{
        "limit":  limit,
        "offset": offset,
    }

    rows, err := db.NamedQuery(Query, params)
    // check error first
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(`GetTransactionsQuery: Failed to execute query`, err)
        return transactions, err
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        transaction := Transactions{}
        rows.StructScan(&transaction)
        transactions = append(transactions, transaction)
    }

    return transactions, err
   }
```